# avoiding for loop in R

Tags: r

### Input:

df1

```
ColA
A
B
C
A B
B C
A C
```

df2

```
ColA               ColB
A B C D E F         1
A B C               2
A B                 3
A                   4
A B D               5
```

### Operation:

1) For each entry in df1 subset data from df2

```
subset(df2,grepl(paste('\\b',df1$colA[i],'\\b',sep=""),df2$ColA,ignore.case = T))
```

2) sum of colB after subsetting

Can i avoid for loop for this operation ? As the data is pretty heavy and it is taking hours to perform for loop. I want to avoid for loop in this case.

### Output:

```
A           1+2+3+4+5 = 15
B                       11
C                        3
A B            1+2+3+5= 11
B C                      3
A C                      0
```

Comment: Please show the expected output.  Looks like you need `merge`

Comment: Can you show how this can be done ?

Comment: Try `sapply(df1$ColA, function(x) sum(df2$ColB[grepl(x, df2$ColA)]))`

Comment: If you look at the example you created, you assigned 'ColA' and 'ColB' as the first column name.  Also, second problem is that you are creating a `factor` column for 'ColB'.  I don't know why you need to put quotes around numeric variable.

Comment: I realized it and was about to remove comment .... let me try again !

Comment: Also, don't put quotes around numeric elements.  By default, data.frame, creates `factor` columns.

Comment: Yes, it is working the way i wanted. However it is taking time .. is there any other method which is real quick. 

PS: Data has 1,000,000 rows.

Comment: Are there duplicates in the 'df1$ColA'

Comment: No, all columns are unique but string size is bigger.

Comment: I meant the elements in 'ColA'

Comment: Yes they are unique as well.

Comment: Perhaps `library(stringi);colSums((vapply(df1$ColA, stri_detect_fixed, str= df2$ColA, numeric(length(df2$ColA)))) * df2$ColB)`

Comment: No, it is not working. It creates a huge vector.

Comment: Ok, then somebody else will come up with a better solution.